# How to get file names in a directory using groovy script?

Tags: groovy, groovyscriptengine

I want to make a list of all the files present in a directory, using groovy.

What would a good code to do the task?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do that:

```
File[] files = new File("/some/path/you/are/interested/in").listFiles()
println( files )
```

That will include directories AND files.  If you just want files then you can do this:

```
File[] files = new File("/some/path/you/are/interested/in").listFiles({ it.isFile() } as FileFilter)
println( files )
```